# $P(X ≥ a) ≤ \frac{Var(X)}{Var(X) + a^2}$ when E(X) = 0

Tags: probability, expectation, variance

The full question is:

Show that if $$E(X) = 0$$ then $$P(x\geq a)\leq \frac{Var[X]}{Var[X] + a^2}$$

Also show that there is an X for which the equality holds.

I was able to note that: $$Var[X] = E[X^2]$$ but that's about as far as I've gotten. I know this is supposed to be a Markov or Chebyshev Inequality question, but that's as far as I've been able to get for now.

Comment: You know Chebyshev's inequality? I think this is just a straightforward appilcation of Chebyshev's inequality.

Comment: I know the basics of it, but I'm struggling to see how exactly it applies here

Comment: cf. e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/169914/70569

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $V$ be the variance of the distribution.For $t,u > 0$, using Markov's inequality, we have the following:
$$
\Pr{\{X \geq t\}} = \Pr{\{X+u \geq t+u\}} \leq \Pr{\{(X+u)^2 \geq (t+u)^2\}}
\leq \frac{E[(X+u)^2]}{(t+u)^2} = \frac{V + u^2}{(t+u)^2}
$$

(the inequality was used in the fourth comparison, for going from the probability to the fraction)

Now, since the above holds for all $u$, we actually would like to minimize the function $\frac{V + u^2}{(t+u)^2}$ with respect to $u$, given that $V$ and $t$ are constants. This is  a simple exercise in differential calculus, the answer being $u = \frac{V}{t}$. Putting that value gives:
$$
\Pr{\{X \geq t\}} \leq \frac{V}{V + t^2}
$$

Comment: Worth mentioning: this is commonly referred to as [Cantelli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Cantelli.27s_inequality).

Comment: Thanks! This helped tremendously. One last question: I'm trying to find a specific X such that this inequality is actually an equality. Any help with that?

Comment: You mean you want a random variable $X$ such that this equality holds, or for every distribution $X$, do you want a possible value that $X$ can take, for which this equality holds?

Comment: I would like a random variable X where the equality holds. Intuitively, I feel like it would be a uniform distribution because it makes a lot of sense for the mean (E[X]) to be equal to 0.

Comment: Ok then. I'll look for a good example.

Comment: For any fixed $t$, consider the r.v. that is $t$ with probability $1/2$ and $-t$ with probability $1/2$. It has expectation $0$ and variance $t^2$; and $\Pr[X \geq t] = \frac{1}{2} = \frac{\operatorname{Var} X}{\operatorname{Var} X + t^2}$. So for any $t$ there exists a r.v. for which the inequality is tight.

Comment: That puts it right. Thank you, @ClementC.

Comment: could you explain why $P(X>a)\leq P(X^2>a^2)$ instead of =?

Comment: @amathnerd,$X^2> a^2$ is equivalent to $|x| > |a|$, which is equivalent to $x > a \text { or } x < -a$, which already covers the case $x > a$. Since it is possible that $x < -a$, it follows that $P(X > a) \leq P(X^2 > a^2)$.